# Converting a list to a map in Scala

Tags: list, scala

I want to create a simple program that calculates someone's age after x years.  so first you assign someone's current age to a variable, and then I want to use map to display the future ages.
What I have so far is:

```
val age = 18
val myList = (1 to 2000).toList
```

Basically, I want the numbers from the list and make it a map key. And for the value, it's a sum of variable and key.  so the map would look like this:
1 -> 19, 2 -> 20, 3 -> 21......

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Consider following a basic tutorial, like the [**tour of scala**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/tour-of-scala.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider mapping to tuples

```
val age = 18
val ageBy: Map[Int, Int] = (1 to 2000).map(i => i -> (age + i)).toMap
ageBy(24)   // res1: Int = 42
```